# Map custom method mapper to Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm creating a poc for using Mapstruct in my future projects.

Now I have one question how to map custom methods to a special target.

For example I have following interface mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface ItemMapper {

    static ItemMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ItemMapper.class);

    @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "number", target = "itemnumber"),
            @Mapping(source = "description", target = "description"),
            @Mapping(source = "itemClass.name", target = "ic"), @Mapping(source = "optionPart", target = "option"),
            @Mapping(source = "plannerCode.code", target = "plannercode"),
            @Mapping(source = "plannerCode.name", target = "planner"),
            @Mapping(source = "vendor.buyerCode.name", target = "buyer"),
            @Mapping(source = "vendor.buyerCode.code", target = "buyerCode"),
            @Mapping(source = "vendor.number", target = "vendor"),
            @Mapping(source = "vendor.name", target = "vendorName"), @Mapping(source = "pcsItem", target = "pcs"),
            @Mapping(source = "specialColourVariant", target = "specialColors"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyBufferGreen", target = "greenLine"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyBufferRed", target = "redine"), @Mapping(source = "leadtime", target = "leadTime"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyStock", target = "stockAC"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyStockSupplier", target = "stockSupplier"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyPurchaseOrder", target = "qtyPo"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyShopOrder", target = "qtySo"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyFirmPlannedOrder", target = "qtyFpo"),
            @Mapping(source = "qtyForecast", target = "qtyForecast"),
            @Mapping(source = "standardCost", target = "stdCost"),
            @Mapping(source = "itemCategory.name", target = "category") })
    ItemViewModel itemToDto(Item item);

    default String locationToLocationDto(Item item) {
        return item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().iterator().next().getLocation().getLocation();
    }

    default double locationToBinType(Item item) {
        return item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().iterator().next().getBinType();
    }

    default double itemToLotsize(Item item) {
        double lotSize = 0;
        if (item.getLotsize() != null) {
            lotSize = item.getLotsize();
        } else if (item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations() != null && !item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().isEmpty()) {
            ItemsOnDetailedLocation location = item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().iterator().next();
            lotSize = location.getLotSize();
        } else {
            lotSize = 0.0;
        }
        return lotSize;
    }

    default double stockRails(Item item) {
        double value = 0;
        for (ItemsOnDetailedLocation detailedLocation : item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations()) {

            if (detailedLocation.getId().getSource().equals("RAILS")) {

                long lotSize2 = detailedLocation.getLotSize();
                long binInStock = detailedLocation.getBinInStock();

                if (binInStock != 0) {

                    value += lotSize2 * (binInStock - 0.5);
                }
            }

        }

        return value;
    }

}
```

In the code you can see the mapping and some default methods with other mapping in it. How can I use those methods in the Mapstruct mappings so that mapstruct uses those methods to fillin values in the fields?

Comment: Did you look in the MapStruct docs? http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html

Answer (score 117, accepted):

As you have multiple default methods that return the same type. You would need to use [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

What this means is that you would need to write your mapper in the following format:

```
@Mapper
public interface ItemMapper {

    // Omitting other mappings for clarity
    @Mapping(source = "item", target = "locationDto", qualifiedByName = "locationDto")
    @Mapping(source = "item", target = "binType", qualifiedByName = "binType")
    @Mapping(source = "item", target = "lotSize", qualifiedByName = "lotSize")
    @Mapping(source = "item", target = "stockRails", qualifiedByName = "stockRails")
    ItemViewModel itemToDto(Item item);

    @Named("locationDto")
    default String locationToLocationDto(Item item) {
        //Omitting implementation
    }

    @Named("binType")
    default double locationToBinType(Item item) {
        //Omitting implementation
    }

    @Named("lotSize")
    default double itemToLotsize(Item item) {
        //Omitting implementation
    }

    @Named("stockRails")
    default double stockRails(Item item) {
        //Omitting implementation
    }
}
```

Some important notes:

- You need to use `@Named` from the MapStruct package
- In `source` you can also specify the name of the parameter of the method
- In `qualifiedByName` you need to specify the value that you have written in `@Named`
- It finds the method not only by the value of `@Named` but also by the parameter type and return type. If it gives a compilation error that it cannot find the method by `@Named` it might be because the types of the parameter and the return value of the method do not fit the types of the `target` and the `source` of the `@Mapping`

I would strongly advise against using expressions for such complicated things. It is much more difficult to get it correct and it is more difficult for maintaining

Comment: I tried removing source part from the mapping, but it did not work. My question is can we skip source parameter from the mapping and method param.

Comment: This is a more direct usage of `@Named` than in the [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).  Super helpful answer for that context as well as this question, which is great!

Answer (score 20):

Simplest way is using powerfull mapstruct [@AfterMapping annotation](https://www.javatips.net/api/mapstruct-master/core-common/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.java). E.g.

```
@AfterMapping
public void treatAdditional(User user, @MappingTarget StudentSkillsTo studentSkillsTo) {
    System.out.println("After mapping!");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Mapstruct can use similar constructions:

```
@Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java(user.getName() != null " +
        " ? user.getName() : "DefaultName")")
```

an **expression** can include any constructions on java
e.g

```
 item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations()
.iterator().next().getLocation().getLocation();
```

if the method is large, then it is worthwhile to take it to another service and call this way

Comment: I tried 
@Mapping(target = "location", expression = "java(item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().iterator().next().getLocation().getLocation())"),
   @Mapping(target = "bintype", expression = "java(item.getItemsOnDetailedLocations().iterator().next().getBinType())")
But without any luck. The fields are still null

Comment: your method, should take both objects.
void itemToDto(@MappingTarget  ItemViewModel  itemViewModel, Item item);

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use them like following

```
@Mapping( target="/*Enter targetFieldName*/", expression="java( /default method which calculates target field/" )
```