# Mapstruct mapping enum name to code and vice a versa

Tags: mapstruct

Have a Maapstruct mapping interface and DTO with various enums.
I have two different enums both of the format:

```
public enum TxAccTypeDto  {
    FINANCE("Finance")
}

public enum TxStatusDto  {
    PENDING("Pending"),
}

public enum TxStatusDto  {
    PENDING("Pending"),
}

public enum ContactMethod {
    TELEPHONE,
```

Issue I have is when converting from Entity fields of type String (not enum) how do I get the right enum used and matching on the Code (value in brackets)?

If used only one enum, then could use this:

```
 default TxAccTypeDto toEnum(final String code) {
    return Arrays.stream(TxAccTypeDto.values()).filter(
            testEnum -> testEnum.getCode().equals(code))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

But it obviously does not know the enum to map to with param String code.
Was hoping I could:

1. just do toEntity(fromDto) and toDto(fromStringCode, forDtoTypeAndFile)
2. only add code per type and not each source/target

Answer (score -1):

This post helps:
[Map custom method mapper to Mapstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521903/map-custom-method-mapper-to-mapstruct)

But means specifing qualifier/individual mapping.  Want it to do it by type and describe mapping once.  Note the problem is from StringToEnum with both having single String param so not qualified

```
@Mappings({
  @Mapping(source = "sourceAccountType", target = "sourceAccountType", qualifiedByName = "txAccTypeDto"),
  @Mapping(source = "targetAccountType", target = "targetAccountType", qualifiedByName = "txAccTypeDto"),
  @Mapping(source = "transactionStatus", target = "transactionStatus", qualifiedByName = "txStatusDto"),
})
```